# Write the equation of a linear graph that doesnt have any points of intersection with the curve with equation y=x^2+2x

Tags: graphing-functions

Help would be appreciated with the following question:
I can probably imagine where it would go and write something totally away but what would be a mathematical way to do this and a proof of answer.
Write the equation of a linear graph that doesn't have any points of intersection with the curve with equation y=x^2+2x

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. A line ("linear graph") will have the form $y = mx + c$

If there were an intersection with $x$ coordinate $X$, at that point, you'll have equality between the two functions, i.e. $X^2 + 2X = mX + c$

That's a quadratic equation. Can you think of what condition must hold for no such intersection to exist (and remember, when discussing graphical intersections at an elementary level, we're always talking about real numbers)?

Can you finish?